# How can I get in a JVM profiler a view similar to the "Timeline Panel" in android's Traceview?

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm, jprofiler, jvisualvm

In the Android platform you've got [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html#timelinepanel), a profiling tool featuring this "Timeline Panel" view where you can easily see the time spent by each method in a historical and structured way. One nested call shows under another, you can zoom in to detail the nesting and see method names.
[image: Timeline Panel]

I'm not an expert in profiling but to me this is an easy way to find bottlenecks in specific use cases or high level routines.

How can I have an equivalent view using a JVM tool like VisualVM?

VisualVM has that "hotspot" table showing method names sorted by "self time" or "total time" which end up highlighting low level methods from the language's core that are called from everywhere, with no nesting or historical relation to anything. I can't figure out how to use it efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such view in VisualVM, but if you take 'Snapshot' of profiled or sampled data, you will get a call-tree view divided by threads. This will allow you to find bottlenecks in your code. See also [Profiling With VisualVM, Part 1](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_1) and [Profiling With VisualVM, Part 2](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_2) to find out more about different profiling settings.